# Android Studio v2.2 Design Mode: Drag & Drop doesn't work, when using "rtl" style

Tags: xml, android-activity, right-to-left, android-studio-2.2, designmode

I changed the `layoutDirection` of my `activity`'s style to `rtl`, so the `res/values/styles.xml` file looks like below:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="ActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
        ...
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

Also consider:

```xml
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">
    ...
</activity>
```

Now **when try to drag & drop some views** (`Widgets`, `Text Fields`, `Images & Media`, ... BUT NO `Layouts`, `Container`, `Transitions`, ...) **to insert them on activity** (inside *design mode* of *XML editor*)**, nothing happens and this error message is produced into "Event Log":**

> **RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside raster**

I hadn't this problem on Android Studio v2.1.1, but since updated it to v2.2.2.0. It seems to be a bug!

I found some Q&A's about above error message, but they had other situations.

Can anyone help me? Is it correctable?

---

Note: There is no problem when I just change `layoutDirection` of root-element of the `activity` (e.g. `LinearLayout`) to `rtl` ... but when I change `layoutDirection` of the `activity`'s `theme`.